# flutter firestore database add MAP type

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've a problem to save a data in firestore database with flutter, I've this two class:

```
class Level {
  final String name;
  final List<Materia> materie;
  Level({
    this.name,
    this.materie,
  });
  Map toJson() {
     return {"name": name, "materie": materie};
  }
}
class Materia extends Taggable {
  final String name;
  Materia({
    this.name,
  });
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [name];
}
```

I want to save this in a MAP in firestore but I receive this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument: Instance of 'Level'
```

This is the code that i use to save my data:

```
Future<bool> saveProfile({String uid, String name, String surname, String address, List<Level> level}) async {
    try {
      Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).updateData({ 'name': name, 'surname': surname, 'address': address, 'level': level.toJson() });
      return true;
    }  catch (e) {
      // throw the Firebase AuthException that we caught
      throw new Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a mapper function in Level class like this:

```dart
Map toJson(){
  return {
    "name" : name,
    "materie" : materie
  };
}
```

Then update your Firebase update code like this:
`Firestore.instance.collection('users').document(uid).updateData({ 'name': name, 'surname': surname, 'address': address, 'level': level.toJson() });`

Comment: Ive try but not work, I've update original question with all save function, I cant call ToJson in a List

Comment: you have declared `level` in your function as `List<Level>` but you are passing a `Level` so change the argument in your function to `Level`.